# Running jobs (scripts) on Beowulf with multiple machines with memory allocation

Tags: mpi

I built a simple Beowulf cluster with one master and 4 nodes (total of 128 cores) following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gvR1eQyxS9I

I was successful to run a "Hello World" program by allocating some cores of my cluster. This is what i used:
$ mpiexec -n 64 -f hosts ./mpi_hello

Now, i know how to run a multithread program, I would like to allocate some memory. I am planning to do some data analysis. 
Each nodes have 16GB of ram. How can I allocate  32GB or 64GB of ram for data analysis?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is a workload manager (such as SLURM) installed on the cluster?

Comment: @Shibli no there is no workload manager installed on the cluster.